# InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to do a classification with LSTM (to do event prediction) I have 320 classes. The dataset is made up of time series data and was created and trained using the following code:

```
def create_dataset(dataset,y, look_back=1):
   dataX, dataY = [], []
   for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):
       a = dataset.iloc[i:(i+look_back)].to_numpy()
       dataX.append(a)
       dataY.append(y.iloc[i + look_back])
   return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

   train_size = int(len(df1) * 0.7)
   test_size = len(df1) - train_size
   train, test = df1.iloc[0:train_size], df1.iloc[train_size:len(df1)]
   print(train.shape, test.shape)
   # reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
   look_back = 10
   #X, Y = create_dataset(dataset, look_back)
   train.msg_code = to_categorical(train.msg_code)
   test.msg_code = to_categorical(test.msg_code)
   trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train,train.msg_code, look_back)
   #print(trainX)
   #print(trainY)
   testX, testY = create_dataset(test,test.msg_code, look_back)
   model = Sequential()
   adam = Adam(lr=0.01)
   #LSTM layers
   chk = ModelCheckpoint('best_model13.pkl', monitor='val_accuracy', save_best_only=True, mode='max', verbose=1)
   model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],trainX.shape[2])))
   #model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
   #model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
   #model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
   # model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
   #Dense layer
   model.add(Dense(320, activation = 'relu'))
   #outputlayer
   model.add(Dense(320,activation='softmax'))
   model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
   #model fitting
   history = model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_data=(testX,testY), epochs=500, batch_size=32,callbacks=[chk],shuffle=False)
   model = load_model('best_model13.pkl')
   scores = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [32 1] [y (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [32 10]
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert (defined at <ipython-input-21-2a944dbcd5e3>:220) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_22113]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Are you sure the outputs of the model and the labels are the same shape?

Comment: i have found my answer here [i added a line before the dense layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809090/tensorflow-2-0-invalidargumenterror-assertion-failed-condition-x-y-did-not)

Comment: @Sarah Rara, If you have found solution that's good. But it would be great, If you can provide working code in the below answer section for the benefit of community. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow 2.0 InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: \[Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809090/tensorflow-2-0-invalidargumenterror-assertion-failed-condition-x-y-did-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my answer here [Tensorflow 2.0 InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809090/tensorflow-2-0-invalidargumenterror-assertion-failed-condition-x-y-did-not)?

I added this line before the dense layer:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
```

Comment: Hi @Sara , welcome to `StackOverFlow` community. It would be much better to add some explanation for your answer, and not just relying on the URL, since it may go unreachable in future, so some explanation would be great. Bests 